# Error code near the 'INSERT' section during incremental ETL insert

Tags: sql, database, etl, incremental-load

```
USE UsineFlex_DW
GO

DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vue_FaitProduction
GO

CREATE VIEW vue_FaitProduction
AS
SELECT
    P.NoProduit,
    U.NoUsine,
    LP.DateProduction,
    M.NoMachine,
    LP.Quantite,
    LP.UnitesEnergieConsommees,
    COUNT(EE.NoEntretienEffectue) AS NombreEntretiensEffectues,
    SUM(DATEDIFF(HOUR, EE.DHDebut, EE.DHFinReelle) * E.SalaireHoraire) AS CoutEntretiensEffectues

FROM
    UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_EntretienEffectue EE
    JOIN UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_Machine M ON M.NoMachine = EE.NoMachine
    JOIN UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_Usine U ON U.NoUsine = M.NoUsine
    JOIN UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_LotProduction LP ON LP.NoMachine = M.NoMachine
    JOIN UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_Produit P ON P.NoProduit = LP.NoProduit
    JOIN UsineFlexInc.dbo.ff_Employe E ON E.NoEmploye = EE.NoEmploye
WHERE 
    LP.DateModification > (
        SELECT DateModification
        FROM UsineFlex_ETLConfig
        WHERE nomTable = 'FAIT_PRODUCTION'
    )

GROUP BY
    P.NoProduit,
    U.NoUsine,
    LP.DateProduction,
    M.NoMachine,
    LP.Quantite,
    LP.UnitesEnergieConsommees;

    -- Charger les données dans la table de fait à partir de la vue

INSERT INTO FAIT_PRODUCTION (RefProduit, RefNoUsine, RefDateProduction, NoMachine, Quantite, UnitesEnergieConsommees, NombreEntretiensEffectues, CoutEntretiensEffectues)
SELECT P.RefProduit, U.RefNoUsine, D.RefDate, FP.NoMachine, FP.Quantite, FP.UnitesEnergieConsommees, FP.NombreEntretiensEffectues, FP.CoutEntretiensEffectues
FROM vue_FaitProduction FP
    INNER JOIN DIM_PRODUIT P ON(P.NoProduit = FP.NoProduit) AND P.Statut = 'Courant'
    INNER JOIN DIM_USINE U ON (U.NoUsine = FP.NoUsine)      
    INNER JOIN DIM_DATE D ON D.RefDate = FP.DateProduction

    UPDATE UsineFlex_ETLConfig
    SET DateModification = getdate()
    WHERE nomTable = 'FAIT_PRODUCTION'

GO
```

I get an error code for near the INSERT section, but I don't know why. Here is the error code:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure vue_FaitProduction, Line 38
> [Batch Start Line 331] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INSERT'.

Comment: Are you trying to run the whole batch in one go? Or are you selecting JUST the INSERT into block before running? If your running the whole file you can only create View once and you need a GO between the View create and your INSERT statement.

Comment: Thank you it works! I was just missing the GO... Also regarding what you're saying about only being able to create the view once, this part ensures that i can run the whole code multiple time without getting an error for the view already existing: DROP VIEW IF EXISTS vue_FaitProduction
GO